# Postgres upsert perform multiple actions _OR_ versioning of events in an "append only" store

Tags: postgresql, upsert, data-versioning, event

### Background

I am running on postgres 9.5

I have a table with events (in theory, it is, currently, an append only store).

Certain event types can appear only once on a given date. (So currently, we have a partial unique index and an upsert to update the "value" column when a conflict occurs <- so this is why it is not a fully append only store)

***The goal: to be able to version the events*** mostly as an audit of past events - mostly in the sense that these events represent a misinterpretation of the facts and have thus been superseded by corrected events

I have, presently, come up with the notion by which I add a Nullable column with a timestamp to each event (I call it `substituted_at`). An event that has been superseded will have the timestamp recorded while the newest events will have that column value remain `NULL`. This should, hopefully, make retrieval of the events easy, for processing, I simply retrieve all events whose `substituted_at` value is `NULL`.

Another solution would have been to have moved the superseded events to an auxiliary table, but that didn't strike me as the way to go (comments?)

(Also, I am open to other propositions)

**Sub goals:**

1. version events whose type can only appear once per date
2. version events whose type can appear multiple times on a given date
3. it should be possible to version an event without supplying a replacement event (in effect removing it from the event store for processing)

---

### Question

I would like to center on sub-goal #1.

It would seem that in case of conflict I need to update the `substituted_at` column with a timestamp and keep all the other values as they are. I would also need to insert a new row with the new data.

It does not seem possible with the [ON CONFLICT Clause](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/sql-insert.html#SQL-ON-CONFLICT).

I would obviously like to do this transactionally.

Also the solution should keep in mind that sub-goal #2 cannot rely on an ON CONFLICT clause - since it is alright to have more than one event per type per date.

Also, sub-goal #3 means that there would be times where no replacement would come at all.

---

As I write these lines, it seems to me that centering on UPSERT to do the heavy lifting is not the robust way I should be heading... Also, in the face of versioning, does the partial unique index make sense anymore?

Comment: sorry for the long question

Comment: please feel free to edit to make it more to the point

Comment: yes I am a developer and not a dba